# Encryption while disk caching

Tags: android, caching, encryption, universal-image-loader

So what I to achieve is to apply **encryption** while **caching images on disk**.
I have decided to go with **Universal Image Loader**, I understand I will have to add an **custom 
disk caching** implementation of my own but I don't know where to start with.

How can I achieve this, encryption while writing byte stream in file and decryption while getting the stream **only from file**.

Any kind of help would be deeply appreciated :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for not replying :P

But I did eventually end up solving it. And here is what I did, maybe It will help anyone else.
All I had to was to create a custom disk cache and custom downloader.
In custom disk caching class, in the method where UIL write byte stream to file, I encrypted the byte stream.
and In custom downloader, I override the method where it take byte stream from file and decrypted it.